# javascript self execution restriction

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have html file with inner self execution js (yes i need inner, not external js file).

and catch chrome error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-ZdElrYr3TtaKtaoIZnHOTnExAQZ24F52ZnNNnSzy16M='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
> 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback.

i add meta tag to head tag and catch exception again

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-ZdElrYr3TtaKtaoIZnHOTnExAQZ24F52ZnNNnSzy16M='">
```

what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the server is sending a `Content-Security-Policy` header with a policy that forbids inline scripts. In that case, adding *another* policy that allows an inline script would not help.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#multiple_content_security_policies)

> The CSP mechanism allows multiple policies being specified for a
> resource, including via the Content-Security-Policy header, the
> Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header and a  element.
>
> You can use the Content-Security-Policy header more than once, as in
> the example below. Pay special attention to the connect-src directive
> here. Even though the second policy would allow the connection, the
> first policy contains connect-src 'none'. **Adding additional policies
> can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource**,
> which means that there will be no connection allowed and, as the
> strictest policy, connect-src 'none' is enforced.

So, you would need to change or remove the policy in the header that blocks inline scripts.